# How to remove referer from get request in Nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, referrer

Is it possible to remove the referer completely using Nginx reverse proxy configuration.

Comment: See proxy_set_header

Comment: @AlexeyTen are you suggesting about 'proxy_set_header referer' ? Please make it clear

Comment: `proxy_set_header Referer "";`

Comment: @AlexeyTen your sol works for me. Please add it as answer so that I could accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set proxy header to an empty string.

`proxy_set_header Referer "";`